# User adding off-topic tag to question to make it inline with their answer

Tags: discussion

**I think it's a problem when a user posts an off-topic answer (because it doesn't respect the language tag) and then suggests an irrelevant edit (adding another language tag) to the question just to make it inline with their answer.**

Recent example: Question about an iOS app made with the Swift language. The question is tagged [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift). The user adds an unsolicited answer in Objective-C, I tell them in a comment that there's no need to do this, but then they *suggest an edit adding the [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) tag to the question*, changing it drastically (who says the question poster even reads this language?).

Right now I have two solutions: "Reject and Edit" *if applicable*, otherwise I just rollback the edit once it's been robo-approved (and add a comment if I think it's necessary).

Am I right to do so?

Comment: I would say yes. In addition, you have downvoted that answer, right?

Comment: Yes, I did downvote it after a while (when I realized that not only it wouldn't be edited/deleted but the author did suggest the bad edit to the question).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct action to take. In addition to downvoting their answer for not being useful to the asker.

If you spot this behavior repeatedly, please flag one of the offending answers for moderator attention, and describe the issue.

Comment: I agree with the direction and disposition here. Answerers shouldn't be editing questions just for the purpose of making an irrelevant answer relevant. That said, I've yet to see a good solution to address this general problem: that many of the frameworks we use today are accessible via two or more languages, and often an answer has little to do with the language and more to do with the framework. Shall we literally need e.g. to ask every possible .NET, Cocoa, iOS, etc. question with every possible language used in such frameworks, rewriting each answer in each possible language?

Comment: @PeterDuniho If a question isn't clear enough about which language it asks about, it should be closed as "unclear what you're asking" until OP edits it to make that clear. (Not necessarily in that order).

Comment: That's not my point. My point is that even if the OP has clearly stated they are using e.g. Swift, the _question_ may pertain not to the language per se but rather something in the framework being used (e.g. Cocoa). Same thing wrt C#/VB.NET and questions that really pertain not to either language, but to .NET itself. Do we really need e.g. separate C# and VB.NET questions asking how to parse a string representation of an integer? In either language, one is calling `System.Integer.Parse()`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: even if the OP has clearly stated they are using a particular language, the question may be more language neutral, and an answer in another language be useful -- particularly since answers aren't for the exclusive benefit of the OP.  When I am searching, I seldom care about the language of the question or answer.

Answer (score -19):

My thought in answering this way was to make the question more broad instead of creating a new question with the new answer. Is the goal to give an answer to the original question, or to provide the community with more information?

Comment: Should you then add a RubyMotion answer to the question? And then a Python one? And a JavaScript one? Because as you may know, we can make iOS apps with many languages. So every iOS+Swift question should get answers in other languages just because it's possible? No, of course. // I would sum it up with **"Don't answer in Java to a Python question."** The questions asks for Swift code, provide Swift code, not Java or anything else. :)

Comment: I would add that my motivation for posting this question on Meta wasn't about the fact that your answer was off-topic - I knew it was. It's a correct answer, but it's also an off-topic answer. No, the question here is  "Was I right to rollback the robo-approved suggested edit to the question". Because it was already my opinion that your suggested edit was a bad idea - it changes the scope of the question just to make your answer on-topic - but I wasn't sure about the course of my actions about it.

Comment: Some constructive criticism for @ChrisBob:  Adding correct information is good provided it's helpful.  Keep in mind we have a "*Too Broad*" question flag, because a Q&A page that isn't cohesive isn't very helpful.  By broadening the question to two languages, you increased its cohesion.  The correct thing for you to do is locate the equivalent objective-c question and answer *it* instead of the swift one.  If an equivalent objective-c question doesn't exist, then we encourage the ask-then-self-answer workflow.  Then the Q&A is cohesive, and thus more likely helpful.

Comment: Editing the question that way is inappropriate.  However, there's nothing wrong with writing an answer and including snippets in another language, or even a fake language (pseudocode), if the question concerns platform APIs or algorithms that aren't language-specific.  In this case, however, your answer doesn't add anything, because the right library call has already been shown.