# Should I add the Swift tag to 'some' Objective-C questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

For example see this question: [Giving UIView rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509547/uiview-with-rounded-corners)

The question itself is tagged with Objective-C but isn't unique to Objective-C. Swift answers also exist for the question.

I fear if I don't add the Swift tag, then the a new question for Swift would be tagged as duplicate and at the same time I fear if I add the Swift tag then some might reject the edit because it won't be aligned with the OP's intention.

Comment: If a question can have two valid yet mutually exclusive languages (ie. you need pure objetive c or pure swift) I think that no language tag should be used.

Comment: @Braiam wouldn't that make it less searchable? And it's not like it would also have an Python or Java tag. Would iOS tag would be more appropriate?

Comment: Define "searchable"? I can find that question using just "UIView with rounded corners" without language.

Comment: @Briaim 1) True you can many other questions without their Objective-C tag. With your logic the even if the quetsion was a pure Objective-C quetsion, still it won't need its tag 2) What I mean is: using [Swift] in the search bar at the top of the screen

Comment: The question lacks code, so anything that accomplish the task should be acceptable, otherwise you get silly titles "UIView with rounded corners in Swift" and "UIView with rounded corners in obj c" and "UIView with rounded corners in what comes next apple?" instead of *a single question with all possible solutions*, which has less rebound rate (or how they call when people come to a page and then leave because it wasn't what they expected?).

Comment: Would you add a "java" tag to a "python" question just because the SDK/library used in the question is also available to Java? No. Same here. The question is not unique to Objective-C, sure: you could also answer with Ruby (RubyMotion), with Xamarin, with Swift, with many other languages... Should we add these languages as tags to the question? Certainly not. So don't add "swift" either.

Comment: @EricD They don't belong to the iOS world. iOS is has 2 languages to use...

Comment: @Honey Did you actually read my comment?! :) There's much more than two languages available for making iOS apps. Objective-C and Swift are just the two most known. There's also Ruby and many other ones like JS and C# ...

Comment: @EricD I did. They aren't common. So if someone is looking for a Swift answer, should he post a new question?

Comment: @Honey Yes, of course. If you want an answer in Java, post a question using Java. If you want an answer in Swift, post a question about Swift. If you can use both, post a question tagged with both! *But* don't go on *other people's posts* and add tags unrelated to the question. The question you link is from 2009 and Swift is from 2014, by the way... :) // Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311285/user-adding-off-topic-tag-to-question-to-make-it-inline-with-their-answer

Comment: @EricD Yes, but the Swift answer there has 42 upvotes. Contrary to what you are saying, this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494498/how-to-control-the-line-spacing-in-uilabel) is from 5 years ago, and it's accepted answer is in Swift, because people understand Swift is the future. Your link is **completely** irrelevant. This is completely on-topic as many people who come there want to find Swift answers. Anyhow, I think we should agree to disagree and wait for others to share their opinion

Comment: @JoshCaswell meaning what?

Comment: @Honey You say in your question `if I add the Swift tag then some might reject the edit because it won't be aligned with the OP's intention` Yes. And they would be right to reject. So that's my answer to your "Should I add..." question: no, please don't.

Comment: Also, [this answer by Robert Harvey](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285266/2227743), quite simply put and perfect: "If the question is tagged objective-c, you should do your best to answer it in Objective-C. It's the same throughout the website; Java questions typically don't get answered in Scala."

Comment: @EricD what you say about the opposite? ie. At first the only way to interact with the iOS framework was objective c, now it isn't, but we still need a canonical with all the solutions for the iOS framework, should we remove the languages tags from a canonical question, to allow people independently the specific language they are using be able to solve their problem? (remember that in this case, the question linked by OP, it has no code at all)

Answer (score 0):

No, don't add [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift).

**Tags are related to the question**

A Swift tag would mean, "This is a question about the Swift language," or "The (code in the) question depends on the Swift language."

**Tags aren't meant to signify the languages used in the answers**

Although the OP could use a language tag to mean, "I'm looking for an answer in *this* language, tags **aren't** meant to indicate anything about *other* possible languages that an answer could be written in.

Just because a Swift answer is added to an Objective-C question, it's not a reason to tag the *question* as [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift).

Comment: How about the opposite? Remove a tag since the language is irrelevant for the question (as this case).

Comment: A question belongs to the community and the OP. I think the community would benefit from adding Swift tag while the OP won't be harmed in any way.

Comment: @Braiam The OP isn't asking if irrelevant tags should be removed. But yes, if the question shouldn't be tagged [tag:objective-c], then it certainly shouldn't be tagged [tag:swift] (for any other reason).